# Concatenating video using FFMPEG wrapper class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ffmpeg

I am trying to concatenate video using NReco.VideoConverter wrapper class made for FFMPEG.

I have three video files with the same frame rate and same frame size.

Here is what I have done.

```
        string toconcatfile = @"C:\Users\Alan\Desktop\Black.mp4";
        string output1 = @"C:\Users\Alan\Desktop\output1.mp4";
        string output2 = @"C:\Users\Alan\Desktop\output2.mp4";
        string finaloutput = @"C:\Users\Alan\Desktop\finaloutput.mp4";
```

All the three videos have a frame rate of 25 and Video frame size yet it fails when I add in toconcatfile to the final conversion method.

It works when its just output1 and output2 meaning there must be a different setting in toconcatfile.

Here is what I have tried.

```
        FFMpegConverter fFMpeg = new FFMpegConverter();


        //Slices first video
        ConvertSettings settings = new ConvertSettings
        {
            VideoFrameRate = 25,
            VideoFrameSize = FrameSize.hd480,
            MaxDuration = startcut,
            AudioSampleRate = 44100

        };

        //Slices second video
        ConvertSettings settings2 = new ConvertSettings
        {
            VideoFrameRate = 25,
            VideoFrameSize = FrameSize.hd480,
            Seek = endcut,
            AudioSampleRate = 44100

        };
        //Copies framerate and size from the previous video to the concatenation video
        ConvertSettings settings3 = new ConvertSettings
        {
            VideoFrameRate = 25,
            VideoFrameSize = FrameSize.hd480,
            MaxDuration = 4,
            AppendSilentAudioStream = true,
            AudioSampleRate = 44100

        };


  string newblack = @"C:\Users\Alan\Desktop\newblack.mp4";

        //Slice method called
        fFMpeg.ConvertMedia(pathtofile, Format.mp4, output1, Format.mp4, settings);
        fFMpeg.ConvertMedia(pathtofile, Format.mp4, output2, Format.mp4, settings2);
        fFMpeg.ConvertMedia(toconcatfile, Format.mp4, newblack, Format.mp4, settings3);

        String[] inputfiles = new String[2];
        inputfiles[0] = output1;
        inputfiles[1] = newblack;
        //inputfiles[1] = output2;


        ConcatSettings concatSettings = new ConcatSettings
        {
            //CustomOutputArgs = output1+" "+ toconcatfile+ " "+output2+ " -filter_complex \"[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]\" -map \"[outv]\" - map \"[outa]\""
        };

        fFMpeg.ConcatMedia(inputfiles, finaloutput, Format.mp4, concatSettings);
```

Can anyone help ?

Edit : I get the exception message - "Invalid argument (exit code: 1)",

Here is the output log of FFMPEG

```
        FFMPEG LOG ITEM - ffmpeg version 3.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the 
            FFmpeg developers
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -   built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -   configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-

dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --

enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -   libavutil      55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -   libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -   libavformat    57. 56.100 / 57. 56.100
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -   libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -   libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -   libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -   libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -   libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
FFMPEG LOG ITEM - Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Users\Alan\Desktop\output1.mp4':
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -   Metadata:
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -     major_brand     : isom
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -     minor_version   : 512
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -     encoder         : Lavf57.56.100
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -   Duration: 00:00:30.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 543 kb/s
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -     Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 852x480 [SAR 3893:2872 DAR 276403:114880], 407 kb/s, SAR 12800:9443 DAR 320:133, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -     Metadata:
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -       handler_name    : VideoHandler
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -     Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -     Metadata:
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -       handler_name    : SoundHandler
FFMPEG LOG ITEM - Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Users\Alan\Desktop\newblack.mp4':
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -   Metadata:
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -     major_brand     : isom
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -     minor_version   : 512
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -     encoder         : Lavf57.56.100
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -   Duration: 00:00:04.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 19 kb/s
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -     Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 852x480 [SAR 160:213 DAR 4:3], 7 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -     Metadata:
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -       handler_name    : VideoHandler
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -     Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 2 kb/s (default)
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -     Metadata:
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -       handler_name    : SoundHandler
FFMPEG LOG ITEM - Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Users\Alan\Desktop\output2.mp4':
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -   Metadata:
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -     major_brand     : isom
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -     minor_version   : 512
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -     encoder         : Lavf57.56.100
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -   Duration: 00:01:34.22, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1058 kb/s
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -     Stream #2:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 852x480 [SAR 3893:2872 DAR 276403:114880], 923 kb/s, SAR 12800:9443 DAR 320:133, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -     Metadata:
Exception thrown: 'NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegException' in NReco.VideoConverter.dll
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -       handler_name    : VideoHandler
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -     Stream #2:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -     Metadata:
FFMPEG LOG ITEM -       handler_name    : SoundHandler
FFMPEG LOG ITEM - [Parsed_concat_0 @ 04ded5e0] Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 852x480, SAR 160:213) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (852x480, SAR 12800:9443)
FFMPEG LOG ITEM - [Parsed_concat_0 @ 04ded5e0] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_0
FFMPEG LOG ITEM - Error configuring complex filters.
FFMPEG LOG ITEM - Invalid argument
```

Comment: when it fails, is there an error code or an exception that gets thrown?

Comment: @tatmanblue yes, I just get invalid argument exception message

Comment: If this is just a wrapper for the ffmpeg cli tool then show the actual command being executed and the complete log from the ffmpeg command.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I have added the complete log. Please have a look. Thanks